# How do I get issues that had a certain status within a certain period?

Tags: jira

I've seen there is a new feature in Jira 4.3, issue status history, but I need more than this. I need to get all the issues of a project that had one or more statuses in a certain period. The JQL query "status was in (Open, Closed)" doesn't take a date into account and the available date fields are for the current status of the issue.

Is it possible to get all issues that had a certain status in a certain period? I have access to the SoapService of JIRA, so I can go via this way as well, although I haven't found a method that gives me back the workflow or something like that to do what I want.

Kind regards

Jannik

Comment: You could author your own [JQL function](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Adding+a+JQL+Function+to+JIRA). `:D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying a jquery of (status = open OR status = closed) AND (resolutionDate > *date* AND resolutionDate < *date2*) would give you all issues with status of open or closed between the dates inserted. Not sure if this is what you were looking for or not.